# Convert np.array to texture kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a code:

```py
array =  np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
```

How to convert my array to kivy texture?
Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can blit your np array into a texture, making sure the size and color format of the texture matches what's in the matrix here is a simple example.

https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/d14837a06d64b481e1a5dca71c46b1c6

the important bits being:

```py
# adjust values and size if you want a different color format
world = np.array(
    [0. for i in range(SIZE[0] * SIZE[1])],
    dtype=np.float32,
)

class Langton(App):
    texture = ObjectProperty()

    def build(self):
        ...
        # adjust colorfmt if your texture is not greyscale
        self.texture = Texture.create(size=SIZE, colorfmt='luminance')
        ...
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def refresh(self, dt):
        self.texture.blit_buffer(world, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='float')
        self.root.ids.world.canvas.flag_update()
```